# Transforming JSON template based on JSON values posted into API

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have got a requirement of building an azure function which transforms data in our COSMOS DB based on the value posted by a calling service.

So consider this JSON template

```
{
    "processExecutionId": 1000,
    "processId": "$PID",
    "parentProcessId": 10,
    "objectNameTag": "$ObjectName",
    "objectName": "bbps.fx",
    "processStartedOn": "$startedOn",
    "processCompletedOn": "$CompletedAt",
    "processExecutionStatusId": 2,
    "configurationPayload": "Actual Config Payload with replaced values by the orchestrator or payload read service",
    "objectMetadata": {
        "jsonPayLoadRead": {
            "messages": "$Message"
        },
        "writeToDB": "$IsWrite"
    }
}
```

This is something we in COSMOS corresponding to a key.

So when a requester application posts that Key it has a JSON object in its body like this

```
{
    "processStartedOn": "2022-01-25 10:10:32",
    "processCompletedOn": "2022-01-25 10:20:25",
    "objectMetadata": {
        "jsonPayLoadRead": {
            "messages": "Data uploaded"
        },
        "writeToDB": "True"
    }
}
```

So the method posting parameters for the template expecting a response from the API after replacing those variables in the template with the values.

The JSON template is not always the same structure. Otherwise we can atleast define a class and can deserialize into it. So what ever the key posted our service needs to take the corresponding JSON template from COSMOS and do the transformation.

So dont know how to handle it the best way or is there is any way to handle this process within COSMOS itself rather than trying using C#.

Please share your thoughts

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you have code you are trying to make work please post it. If there are error messages, please include those too.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a TemplateType property in your class so that you know the various options you have and based on that you know what class to use, there are also ways to stream from cosmos directly without using classes at all but it depends a little what you are trying to achieve if you just need to hand over to another app or not then you can stream from cosmos without even knowing what the structure is